# Why are two different "Well" cards included in the new version of Agricola?

Tags: agricola

In the updated Mayfair edition of Agricola, I found two Major Improvement cards for the Well. One costs three stone and one wood (as it did in the original version of the game), the other costs three stone and one clay. In other respects the cards were identical. In a scan through the rules, I could only find mention of the Well costing stone and wood, and no indication of when or how the "stone and clay" card should be used - though I did spot a picture of the "stone and clay" card in one of the illustrations.

What is the purpose of the two alternative versions of the Well, and how do I decide which one to use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Well that shows three Stone and one Clay is a misprint, which was packaged up with the rest of the cards. The other well was included separately from the rest of the cards as a replacement to fix it. So you should only use the one that is the same as the original version, that costs three Stone and one Wood.

Sources for this information:

https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1695453/2016-version-extra-well-major-improvement-card-box

and

https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1587110/extra-well-card